# Did Vader ever face another Force user in aerial/space combat, aside from Luke in Ep. IV?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith, darth-vader

The formerly canonical book *Shadows of the Empire* (set between the end of *The Empire Strikes Back* and the beginning of *Return of the Jedi*)  contains the following passage:

> Vader had forgotten how much he enjoyed piloting his Interceptor, it had been so long. It came back quickly.
>
> The enjoyment did not last. Almost effortlessly, he blew three, four, five of the Rebel ships into smoking pieces. It was... disappointing. **The Force was not strong in any of them; it was no real challenge. Some were skilled, true, but mere skill could not defeat the dark side. He had hoped for better competition**.

This makes me wonder if Vader ever faced other Force users in aerial/space combat.  Obviously, he pursues Luke's X-Wing in *A New Hope*, but are there any other examples of Vader flying against a Force user?

Comment: __Why the downvote?__ I don't see anything wrong with this question. You have my +1.

Comment: I assume that you mean since he became Vader? I am sure there are clone wars instances.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Vader faces Ezra Bridger, Kanan Jarrus, and Ahsoka Tano

In the canonical *Star Wars: Rebels* "[Siege of Lothal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars_Rebels_episodes#Season_2_.282015.E2.80.9316.29)", Vader faced Ezra Bridger, Kanan Jarrus, and Ahsoka Tano in a space battle.

In this confrontation, Kanan and Ahsoka are helping inside the cockpit while Ezra is at the guns/turrets. These three Force users are actively participating in the fight, they are not merely passengers. Vader eventually senses something's up and exclaims

> VADER: The apprentice lives.

Comment: Both video links are dead

Answer (score 11):

## Anakin has a space battle with Asajj Ventress (Legends)

In the 2D *Clone Wars* cartoon, [Anakin dogfights with Asajj Ventress over (and through the streets of) Muunilinst](https://youtu.be/XVk9lPotcW4?t=1920).

[image: Ventress' "fanblade" fighter]

Her skill in the Force and unique fighter design cause the two pilots to be fairly evenly matched. At one point, he even mutters "I have you now" as a call-forward to *A New Hope*. The battle ends when she jumps to hyperspace to lure him to Yavin 4.

Comment: And to top it off, she lures him to Yavin IV where they have a lightsaber battle!

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the others here, Vader has had some run-ins in the new comic book series.  I realize that this is also against Luke, but... you did say "in Ep. IV" :)

Luke rams Vader's Tie fighter with his X-Wing after Vader takes out nearly an entire squadron.  Both crash on VROGAS VAS.  From Vader Down #1:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know about **Vader** but Anakin certainly did during the Clone Wars he flew against Ventress and I think Dukoo but that might not be accurate

Comment: He also flew against Obi-Wan as well (who was disguised - Anakin didn't know). Having said that, this actually answers an entirely different question.

Comment: Really What question?